# How to restore the xfce panel settings?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

The xfce panel has disappeared. When I run `xfce4-panel` the panel starts and works like a charm, but shows:

```
(xfce4-mixer-plugin:1816): libxfce4mixer-CRITICAL **: xfce_mixer_get_track: assertion `GST_IS_MIXER (card)' failed
(xfce4-mixer-plugin:1816): xfce4-mixer-plugin-CRITICAL **: xfce_mixer_plugin_set_card: assertion `GST_IS_MIXER (card)' failed
(xfce4-mixer-plugin:1816): xfce4-mixer-plugin-CRITICAL **: xfce_mixer_plugin_set_track: assertion `GST_IS_MIXER_TRACK (track)' failed
```

How do you restore the xfce panel state?

Xubuntu 10.04 (with Xfce 4.6).

Comment: "mixer" makes it sound like an audio issue.  It may just be the volume adjuster part of the panel that is having trouble loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know the actual reason for this failure, but It resolved itself after I checked "Save session for future logins" and restarted.

The panel can also be restarted from the command line using:

```
xfce4-panel -r
```

Or the more verbose:

```
xfce4-panel --restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset the panels:

```
xfce4-panel --exit  
rm -R ~/.config/xfce4/panel  
xfce4-panel
```

---

If `xfce4-panel --exit` doesn't work, try:

```
xfce4-panel --quit
```

Using xfce4-panel 4.11.0 (Xfce 4.10).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the same errors after this reset. (I'm willing to try something harder ;)

Comment: Go into synaptic (if you can) and delete all the packages that come under the search "xfce panel" that don't look important.